# How do you continue an action after you add a break in a PHP Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So here's the issue. I have two PHP files (one.php and two.php). The first loop starts from 0 and stops at 77.

The next loop starts from from row 78 and stops at 300. This partially works. For some reason all of the rows from two.php are not displaying. I figure that one.php's loop is preventing two.php from fully running. I am using advanced custom fields (ACF) in WordPress.

```
 /*** One.php  ***/
<?php
  if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
  $i = 0;
    // loop through the rows of data
      while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
      $i++;

          continue;
      if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) 
      {
          the_sub_field('feature_article_link'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_title'); 
      } 
      if( $i > 77 )
      {
          break;
      }
      endwhile;
  else :
      // no rows found
  endif;
?>


 /*** Two.php  ***/
<?php
  if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
  $i = 0;
    // loop through the rows of data
      while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
      $i++;
      if($i<79)
          continue;
      if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) 
      {
          the_sub_field('feature_article_link'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_title'); 
      } 
      if( $i > 100 )
      {
          break;
      }


      endwhile;
  else :
      // no rows found
  endif;
?>
```

Both files are included in one PHP template file:

Comment: maybe you dont need `continue`

Comment: @ Sysix Ok, do you have alternatives or a suggestion?

Comment: tell me which rows should be outputed? use the `$i` variable as counter ;)

Comment: I don't see why the first loop should stop after 77 - it shouldn't do anything interesting since there's the `continue` around the line number 8. The second should run from 79 to 100, because of the break. The second thing - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try adding  reset_rows(); at the beginning of the second file.

Comment: @Sysix The first file should output row 0 to 77. The second row should output row 78 to 100

Comment: @Picard The first file one.php should output row 0 to 77. The second file (two.php) should output row 78 to 100

Comment: So, why there's `if( $i > 40 )` if you want `77` ? Why there's `continue` in the 8th line - how do you expect the 9th line and so one to be executed?

Comment: @Mariton I edited my answers. One of my solutions should work.

Comment: *I do not think your code does what you think it does*: https://youtu.be/F8y-qy9N01I

Comment: @Picard Good point. I updated my questions to break at the 77th row instead of on the 40th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your intern loop of `have_rows` you can easily continue to loop your rows.

here is an code:

```
/*** One.php  ***/
<?php
  if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
  $i = 0;
    // loop through the rows of data
      while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
      $i++;

      if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) 
      {
          the_sub_field('feature_article_link'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_title'); 
      } 
      if( $i >= 77 )
      {
          break;
      }
      endwhile;
  else :
      // no rows found
  endif;
?>


 /*** Two.php  ***/
<?php
  if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
      while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
      $i++;

      if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) 
      {
          the_sub_field('feature_article_link'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
          the_sub_field('feature_title'); 
      } 
      if( $i >= 100 )
      {
          break;
      }


      endwhile;
  else :
      // no rows found
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm

Comment: which of both solution? so I can edit my answer and help other people.

Comment: The first answer seemed to work for me. I just tested it